# Cleveref's namecref usage in etoolbox' tests

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, expansion, cleveref, etoolbox

I am currently trying to create new commands to add the correct French article in front of the cross-references when required (for example "**la** figure XX" or "**le** chapitre XX").

My initial idea was to create commands like `\acref` and `\Acref` somehow like that:

```
\newcommand{\acref}[1]{%
\def\rtype{\namecref{#1}}% namecref will produce something like "figure"
\def\article{{\bf error:[\rtype](#1)} }% default value to help debugging
\ifstrequal{\rtype}{figure}{\def\article{la }}{}%
\article\cref{#1}\xspace
}
```

I also tried adding `\expandafter` around `\ifstrequal` like that:

```
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\rtype}{figure}{\def\article{la }}{}%
```

And I tried some other combinations of commands that I do not master, with bad results.

All my attempts produced an invalid output, either always using the article for figure (as it is currently the only one I try to test) because both branches of the conditional statement are executed (with too much `\expandafter`) or it never enters the true branch.

Minimal compiling and not working example:

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xspace}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures} % instead of fig.

\newcommand{\acref}[1]{%
\def\rtype{\namecref{#1}}% namecref will produce something like "figure"
\def\article{{\bf error:[\rtype](#1)} }% default value to help debugging
\ifstrequal{\rtype}{figure}{\def\article{la }}{}%
\article\cref{#1}\xspace
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Title}
  \label{sec:title}

  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:caption}
  \end{figure}

  Test with figure: \acref{fig:caption}. % should print "la figure" but prints error:...

  Test with section: \acref{sec:title}. % should print error:...
\end{document}
```

---

I read that `etoolbox` does not expand its arguments in most of its tests, including `\ifstrequal`.
I had the idea to create a list containing the result of `\namecref` as there is `\listeadd` which expands its item argument and then test if that list contains the text "figure".
However, when I tried (`\listeadd{\mylist}{\namecref{#1}}`), `pdflatex` stopped compiling and returned (filtered):

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
```

So, is `\namecref` unexpandable?

---

Really close questions that I failed to make work in my case:

- [Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et)
- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22106

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is there something stopping you from simply writing `\crefname{figure}{la figure}{les figures}`?

Comment: I agree with@Mico's proposal. In the rare cases where  the article wouldn't be used in French, you always can type the name  of the environment and use a plain `\ref`.

Comment: (perhaps I should edit my question?)
No, this is not a solution in my case: first, the article would be included in the link (when using hyperref and because I like to have "figure" included in the link); then, and mostly, because I often use `\cref` like `some text (\cref{fig:lbl})` which would be incorrectly expanded as "some text (la figure 2)".
@Bernard and, I find using `\ref` defeats one advantage of `\cref` that allows to change easily all prefixes for a given label type.

Comment: Happily you do not write in Latin or Greek (I suppose) – you'd have to provide for the different possibilities of declensions and cases (albeit one rarely uses the vocative for a figure or a table, as far as I know).

Comment: You might be interested in [xcref](https://github.com/frougon/xcref). It's a proof of concept but works (see the examples in French and German). Some names had to be changed in the latest commit, which haven't propagated to the manual yet, but this only concerns one particular feature.

Comment: @frougon Indeed it seems interesting, however I cannot make it to compile correctly. The first execution of `pdflatex` produces a PDF with `??`. The second one throws the error `Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \text_titlecase:nn` on line 109 of the french example (`... via \textsf{xcref} \fxcref{sec-exemples}`.

Comment: Your `expl3` is too old . `\text_titlecase:nn` was introduced in `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 1` (previously, there were other functions for the same thing in `expl3`, but they behaved differently; this is the name changing I mentioned [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539115/cleverefs-namecref-usage-in-etoolbox-tests?noredirect=1#comment1362203_539115)). Besides, requiring at least two compilations when using references is quite normal—this is how references work and explains the `??` after only one compilation run.

Comment: If it's too difficult to upgrade `expl3`, [xcref commit 68342b43f24](https://github.com/frougon/xcref/commit/68342b43f24dcfc7e4a0ad0ee1c45a62250366b1) should work for you, but beware that it will break when your LaTeX becomes up-to-date.

Comment: It works, however it produces links including the prefix with [nameinlink] from cleveref. I tried to read your source, but it is far above my current level. Do you locally modify inner cleveref's variables or do you produce yourself the text of the cross-reference? If the latter is true, how do you test the label type?

Comment: You should use @frougon, otherwise I'm not notified. The `nameinlink` thing is one of the biggest things I'm unhappy about, but I believe it can't be fixed using my approach without hacking `cleveref` (the other being that it is a brute force approach). The answer to your question is “the former”: when they know the circumstances (combination of `form` and `preposition` for French, but for German, the `case` also matters), my commands call `\crefname` and  `\Crefname` for all known ref types (this is where it is brute force), which locally changes the results produced by `cleveref`.

Comment: Look for `\@@_call_crefname:nnn` and `\@@_call_Crefname:nnn` in my code, maybe this will help you understand. I believe what you wanted to do can't be done this way because `cleveref` doesn't produce its results in an “expandable” manner (you can't get the result in `\x` using `\edef\x{...}`, where `...` contains simple calls to `cleveref` macros).

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505835/73317) of mine too: it shows how you can retrieve the `cleveref` name (theorem, proposition, etc.) associated to a given ref, programmatically transform it depending on which one it is, and also retrieve the number/letter/etc. (what `cleveref` calls the “label”) associated to the ref. In fact, I think the first part is exactly what you need for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use `\cref@gettype` to get the type of a `cleveref` reference in a macro of your choice (`\mycref@type` in the code below), then execute special code depending on the result. `\cref@gettype` expects that the `\r@〈reference〉@cref` macro has already been defined, which is done when the `\newlabel` command present in the `.aux` file is executed after the first compilation run with the `〈reference〉` in question. Therefore, my code checks whether the `\r@〈reference〉@cref` macro is defined and if not, prints `??` in the document along with the usual message on the terminal and in the log file:

> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

I removed the use of `xspace` in your code, because [the original author of `xspace` nowadays advises against using it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/73317) (moreover, as egreg pointed out, `xspace` wouldn't be useful here, since your macro takes an argument). I changed the `fig:caption` label to `fig-caption`, otherwise with `cleveref` and `:` as an active character,<sup>1</sup> you'll encounter problems. Please also note that I use `amsthm` for the theorem in the example. Should you use theorem environments defined with `\newtheorem` from the LaTeX kernel, you'd find that the `cleveref` type for theorems using a shared counter is not necessarily what you expect (you'd get the name of the shared counter instead of the “specific” name; this doesn't happen with `amsthm` theorem environments).

Finally, don't forget to load `cleveref` last! :-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsthm}             % only for the demo
%\usepackage{hyperref}          % usually last, but before cleveref
\usepackage{cleveref}           % load this package last

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}    % instead of fig.
\crefname{theorem}{théorème}{théorèmes}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Let's borrow \str_case:onF from expl3 (\cs_new_eq:NN is like \let but checks
% that the “destination” command name doesn't already exist).
\cs_new_eq:NN \mycref@str@oswitch \str_case:onF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\acref}[1]{%
  \ifcsname r@#1@cref\endcsname
    \cref@gettype{#1}{\mycref@type}%
    \mycref@str@oswitch{\mycref@type}
      {{figure}{la }%
       {theorem}{le }%
%      {...}{...}% you can add as many cases as you want!
      }
      {\errmessage{%
         My package: unknown reference type for label '#1':
         '\unexpanded\expandafter{\mycref@type}'}%
      }%
  \else
    \G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{Reference `#1' on page \thepage\space undefined}%
  \fi
  \cref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \section{Title}\label{sec-title}

  \begin{theorem}\label{th-some-theorem}
    This is a theorem.
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering X
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig-caption}
  \end{figure}

  Test with figure: \acref{fig-caption}.

  Test with theorem: \acref{th-some-theorem}.

% Test with section: \acref{sec-title}. % prints an error, as expected

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line and recompile until LaTeX is happy (because of the change in `\newlabel` syntax this implies), you'll get:

[image]

---

**Footnote**

1. Which will normally be the case if you use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` with the pdfTeX engine.

Comment: By the way, `\xspace` is and has always been pretty useless in macros with arguments.

Comment: @egreg I believe the way the OP used `xspace` here was correct, wasn't it? Once the OP's `\acref` is expanded, `\xspace` would see a period, or a space, or... ?

Comment: @frougon ... well, I was reading and trying to adapt the link you gave to post something like you just did. I will accept the answer after some testing. I get `! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.` if I use `hyperref`, however the second compilation works perfectly and produces the correct result. What I was trying to do produced the same but with `\@firstoftwo` and I was trying to get rid of that. Perhaps it is normal for first compilation?
As for cleveref with babel, I did something probably ugly but working, I renewed to encapsulate inside otherlanguage to locally disable `:`.

Comment: `hyperref` and standard LaTeX use different syntaxes for `\newlabel` (and `cleveref` also its own!), so when adding or removing one of these packages, it's quite expected to have errors on the first run. In these cases, just recompile or remove the `.aux` file. There is no problem that I know of with `\usepackage[french]{babel}` if you don't use active characters in reference names (i.e., inside the argument of `\label`). I always use `-` instead of `:` in my label names for this reason (when writing in French). One more thing: `hyperref` must be loaded before `cleveref`!

Comment: The example works with `hyperref`, just see where I load it in the latest edit, and compile twice. Regarding package load order, see [Should babel package call be placed at the end of the preamble?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150788/73317).

Comment: @frougon The `\xspace` trick might only be useful for adding the space which would be gobbled by a macro with no argument. Since spaces after mandatory arguments *are* preserved, doing the check is simply a waste of time.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the explanation. I have used `xspace` very little all in all and that was long ago, so I didn't remember very well how it works.